# Async task crashing during doInBackground()

Tags: java, android

I am having a problem with my android app that i'm trying to develo,apparently it crushes when it's to execute doInBackground,my logcat looks like this:

```
08-19 04:40:57.046: D/request!(4766): starting
08-19 04:40:57.125: W/dalvikvm(4766): threadid=9: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40018578)
08-19 04:40:57.132: E/AndroidRuntime(4766): FATAL EXCEPTION: AsyncTask #1
08-19 04:40:57.132: E/AndroidRuntime(4766): java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occured while executing doInBackground()
08-19 04:40:57.132: E/AndroidRuntime(4766):     at android.os.AsyncTask$3.done(AsyncTask.java:200)
08-19 04:40:57.132: E/AndroidRuntime(4766):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerSetException(FutureTask.java:274)
08-19 04:40:57.132: E/AndroidRuntime(4766):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.setException(FutureTask.java:125)
08-19 04:40:57.132: E/AndroidRuntime(4766):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:308)
08-19 04:40:57.132: E/AndroidRuntime(4766):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:138)
08-19 04:40:57.132: E/AndroidRuntime(4766):     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1088)
08-19 04:40:57.132: E/AndroidRuntime(4766):     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:581)
08-19 04:40:57.132: E/AndroidRuntime(4766):     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1019)
08-19 04:40:57.132: E/AndroidRuntime(4766): Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Target host must not be null, or set in parameters.
08-19 04:40:57.132: E/AndroidRuntime(4766):     at org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.determineRoute(DefaultRequestDirector.java:577)
08-19 04:40:57.132: E/AndroidRuntime(4766):     at org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.execute(DefaultRequestDirector.java:292)
08-19 04:40:57.132: E/AndroidRuntime(4766):     at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:555)
08-19 04:40:57.132: E/AndroidRuntime(4766):     at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:487)
08-19 04:40:57.132: E/AndroidRuntime(4766):     at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:465)
08-19 04:40:57.132: E/AndroidRuntime(4766):     at com.example.prova1.JSONParser.makeHttpRequest(JSONParser.java:110)
08-19 04:40:57.132: E/AndroidRuntime(4766):     at com.example.prova1.Login$AttemptLogin.doInBackground(Login.java:159)
08-19 04:40:57.132: E/AndroidRuntime(4766):     at com.example.prova1.Login$AttemptLogin.doInBackground(Login.java:1)
08-19 04:40:57.132: E/AndroidRuntime(4766):     at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:185)
08-19 04:40:57.132: E/AndroidRuntime(4766):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:306)
08-19 04:40:57.132: E/AndroidRuntime(4766):     ... 4 more
08-19 04:41:04.726: E/WindowManager(4766): Activity com.example.prova1.Login has leaked window com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView@4054b1a8 that was originally added here
08-19 04:41:04.726: E/WindowManager(4766): android.view.WindowLeaked: Activity com.example.prova1.Login has leaked window com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView@4054b1a8 that was originally added here
08-19 04:41:04.726: E/WindowManager(4766):  at android.view.ViewRoot.<init>(ViewRoot.java:263)
08-19 04:41:04.726: E/WindowManager(4766):  at android.view.WindowManagerImpl.addView(WindowManagerImpl.java:171)
08-19 04:41:04.726: E/WindowManager(4766):  at android.view.WindowManagerImpl.addView(WindowManagerImpl.java:114)
08-19 04:41:04.726: E/WindowManager(4766):  at android.view.Window$LocalWindowManager.addView(Window.java:424)
08-19 04:41:04.726: E/WindowManager(4766):  at android.app.Dialog.show(Dialog.java:241)
08-19 04:41:04.726: E/WindowManager(4766):  at com.example.prova1.Login$AttemptLogin.onPreExecute(Login.java:126)
08-19 04:41:04.726: E/WindowManager(4766):  at android.os.AsyncTask.execute(AsyncTask.java:391)
08-19 04:41:04.726: E/WindowManager(4766):  at com.example.prova1.Login.onClick(Login.java:93)
08-19 04:41:04.726: E/WindowManager(4766):  at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:2485)
08-19 04:41:04.726: E/WindowManager(4766):  at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:9080)
08-19 04:41:04.726: E/WindowManager(4766):  at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:587)
08-19 04:41:04.726: E/WindowManager(4766):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
08-19 04:41:04.726: E/WindowManager(4766):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:130)
08-19 04:41:04.726: E/WindowManager(4766):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3687)
08-19 04:41:04.726: E/WindowManager(4766):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
08-19 04:41:04.726: E/WindowManager(4766):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
08-19 04:41:04.726: E/WindowManager(4766):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:867)
08-19 04:41:04.726: E/WindowManager(4766):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:625)
08-19 04:41:04.726: E/WindowManager(4766):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
08-19 04:41:05.070: D/dalvikvm(4766): GC_CONCURRENT freed 235K, 48% free 2955K/5639K, external 507K/517K, paused 3ms+3ms
```

My java code is like this;

```
public class Login extends Activity implements OnClickListener{
    private EditText user, pass;

    private Button mSubmit, mRegister;

     // Progress Dialog
    private ProgressDialog pDialog;

    // JSON parser class

    JSONParser jsonParser = new JSONParser();

    //php login script location:

    //localhost :
    //testing on your device

    //put your local ip instead,  on windows, run CMD > ipconfig
    //or in mac's terminal type ifconfig and look for the ip under en0 or en1



    //testing on Emulator:

 private static final String LOGIN_URL = "login_url";


  //testing from a real server:


    //JSON element ids from repsonse of php script:

    private static final String TAG_SUCCESS = "success";

    private static final String TAG_MESSAGE = "message";



    @Override

    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

       super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_login);
      //setup input fields

        user = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.username);

        pass = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.password);

        //setup buttons

        mSubmit = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);

        mRegister = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button2);
      //register listeners

        mSubmit.setOnClickListener(this);

        mRegister.setOnClickListener(this);
  }

    @Override

    public void onClick(View v) {

        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        switch (v.getId()) {
        case R.id.button1:
                new AttemptLogin().execute();
            break;
        case R.id.button2:
             Intent i = new Intent(this, Register.class);

                startActivity(i);
            break;

        default:
            break;
     }

    }

    class AttemptLogin extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {
      /**


         * */

        boolean failure = false;

        @Override

        protected void onPreExecute() {

            super.onPreExecute();

            pDialog = new ProgressDialog(Login.this);

            pDialog.setMessage("Attempting login...");
         pDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
         pDialog.setCancelable(true);
        pDialog.show();

        }
    @Override

        protected String doInBackground(String... args) {

            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

             // Check for success tag

            int success;


            String username = user.getText().toString();//my app seems to be crushing here


            String password = pass.getText().toString();

            try {

                // Building Parameters

                List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();

                params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("username", username));

                params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("password", password));

                Log.d("request!", "starting");

                // getting product details by making HTTP request

                JSONObject json = jsonParser.makeHttpRequest(

                       LOGIN_URL, "POST", params);



                // check your log for json response

                Log.d("Login attempt", json.toString());



                // json success tag

                success = json.getInt(TAG_SUCCESS);

                if (success == 1) {

                    Log.d("Login Successful!", json.toString());
              Intent i = new Intent(Login.this, ReadComments.class);

                    finish();

                    startActivity(i);

                    return json.getString(TAG_MESSAGE);

                }else{

                    Log.d("Login Failure!", json.getString(TAG_MESSAGE));

                    return json.getString(TAG_MESSAGE);

                }

            } catch (JSONException e) {

                e.printStackTrace();

            }

            return null;

        }

        /**

         * After completing background task Dismiss the progress dialog

         * **/

        protected void onPostExecute(String file_url) {

            // dismiss the dialog once product deleted

            pDialog.dismiss();

            if (file_url != null){

                Toast.makeText(Login.this, file_url, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

            }

        }

    }

}
```

any assistance will be highly appreciated!!

Comment: So, the two most important pieces of infomation are `08-19 04:40:57.132: E/AndroidRuntime(4766): Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Target host must not be null, or set in parameters.` and `08-19 04:40:57.132: E/AndroidRuntime(4766):     at com.example.prova1.Login$AttemptLogin.doInBackground(Login.java:159)`...I suggest you find line 159 in `AttemptLogin` and find out why the required value is `null`....

Comment: Also, this might be an excellent opportunity to learn how to use the debugger...

Comment: Or a logger.  This line of code: `JSONObject json = JsonParser.makeHttpRequest( LOGIN_URL, "POST", params);` looks like "LOGIN_URL" might be malformed (no host name, as mentioned above).

Comment: @MadProgrammer Made a switch from Swing to Android? :p

Comment: I recommend you don't start activity from doInBackground,it's better that do onPostExecute

Comment: @LittleChild Even worse, teaching myself IOS/Objective C

Comment: pDialog.dismiss(); call this method before intenting activity...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your log very clearly says:

```
Target host must not be null, or set in parameters.
```

As has been pointed out, `LOGIN_URL` may be malformed. I suggest you `Log.v()` it and see for yourself.

Answer (score 0):

Try to save username and password in `onPreExecute()` because you can't do reference to interface component in `doInBackground()`

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use directly your widgets like `EditText, TextView, Buttons` etc in `doInBackground()` preferable use these in `onPreExecute()` method. Secondly if you have to use these in `doInBackground()` method you should use `runOnUIThread()`

Another thing is you are calling another activity from `doInBackground()` and dismiss your dialog in `onPostExecute()` you should return your `json.getString(TAG_MESSAGE)` string from `doInBackground()` and after `dialog.dismiss()` start your next Activity see code below:

```
                @Override
                protected String doInBackground(String... args) {
                          String username, password;


                         // Check for success tag

                        int success;

                        runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {

                            @Override
                            public void run() {

                                 username = user.getText().toString();


                                password = pass.getText().toString();
                            }
                        });

                       //do your other stuff

                         try {

                        // Building Parameters

                        List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();

                        params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("username", username));

                        params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("password", password));

                        Log.d("request!", "starting");

                        // getting product details by making HTTP request

                        JSONObject json = jsonParser.makeHttpRequest(

                               LOGIN_URL, "POST", params);



                        // check your log for json response

                        Log.d("Login attempt", json.toString());



                        // json success tag

                        success = json.getInt(TAG_SUCCESS);

                        if (success == 1) {




                             return json.getString(TAG_MESSAGE);

                        }else{



                           return json.getString(TAG_MESSAGE);

                        }

                    } catch (JSONException e) {

                        e.printStackTrace();

                    }


                    }

     protected void onPostExecute(String file_url) {

                    // dismiss the dialog once product deleted

                    pDialog.dismiss();

                    if (file_url.equals("success message")){

                        Toast.makeText(Login.this, file_url, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                         Intent i = new Intent(Login.this, ReadComments.class);

                         finish();

                         startActivity(i);

                    } else{
                    Log.d("Login Failure!", json.getString(TAG_MESSAGE));
}



                }
```

you can read about `runOnUiThread()` from [here](http://developer.android.com/tools/testing/activity_testing.html).
hope this will help you.

Comment: @Khan.... But i think if it will issue of UiThread then it will show:Can't create handler inside thread that has not called Looper.prepare() exception in doInbackgroung() block ,but it is showing IllegalStateException.

Comment: i had malformed the url:-(

Answer (score 0):

Use Below Code .

```
class LoginTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, JSONObject> {

        private ProgressDialog progressDialog;

        String username;
        String password;


        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
             username = user.getText().toString();
             password = pass.getText().toString();
            progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(mContext);
            progressDialog.setMessage("Loading...");
            progressDialog.setCancelable(false);
            progressDialog.setTitle(R.string.message_progress_title);
            progressDialog.show();
        }

        @Override
        protected JSONObject doInBackground(String... params) {

            try {
                // Building Parameters
                List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
                params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("username", username));
                params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("password", password));
                Log.d("request!", "starting");
                // getting product details by making HTTP request
                JSONObject json = jsonParser.makeHttpRequest(LOGIN_URL, "POST", params);

                return jsonObject;
            }

            @Override
            protected void onPostExecute(JSONObject jsonObject) {
                if(progressDialog.isShowing()) {
                    progressDialog.dismiss();
                }
                if(jsonObject != null) {
                    Log.i(TAG, "Login response : " + jsonObject);
                    try {
                        success = json.getInt(TAG_SUCCESS);

                        if (success == 1) {
                            Intent i = new Intent(Login.this, ReadComments.class);
                            startActivity(i);
                            finish();
                        } 
                        else {
                            Toast.makeText(mContext, getResources().getString(R.string.login_failed), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        }
                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
                else {
                    Toast.makeText(mContext, getResources().getString(R.string.connection_error), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

> You have the error named leaked window because you are trying to
>   open an Activity from doInBackground(...) and pDialog(ProgressDialog) is still
>   open you haven't dismiss that.

So, declare `success` variable globally(where you declare `failure` variable). Try to open new `Activity` or `view update` in `onPostExecute(...)`

code snippet for `onPostExecute(...)`

```
protected void onPostExecute(String file_url) {

 // dismiss the dialog once product deleted
 if(pDialog != null) {
     pDialog.dismiss();
      if (success == 1) {

            Log.d("Login Successful!", json.toString());
            Intent i = new Intent(Login.this, ReadComments.class);
            finish();
            startActivity(i);
     }
     if (file_url != null){
       Toast.makeText(Login.this, file_url, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

    }
  }
}
```